# How can I get background in FF and IE10?

Tags: javascript

I need get value #C1C1C1, but how can I get it?

Demo https://jsfiddle.net/f8e37r1d/2/

I read [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle) aticle, but i don't know what I should do.

HTML

```
<div id="test">click</div>
<div id="getcolor"></div>
<div id="res"></div>
```

CSS

```
#test {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    text-align: center;
    border-width: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: red;
}
#getcolor{
  background: #C1C1C1;
}
```

JS

```
test.onclick = function(e) {

    var Brush = function(id){
        console.log('internal func');

        var color1 = document.getElementById('getcolor').style.background;
        console.log(color1); // color1 is empty in FF

      var color2 = window.getComputedStyle(getcolor,null).getPropertyValue('background');
      console.log(color2); // color2 is empty in FF but work in Chrome
    }

    Brush(e.target.id);
}
```

Comment: No modern browser stores the background color as " #C1C1C1", it is stored as `rgb(r, g, b)`. Also, `background` is not a real CSS property, it is a shortcut to multiple properties, like `background-color`, `background-image` etc.

Comment: @Teemu: Yes I know about `background-color` but the result is the same: https://jsfiddle.net/f8e37r1d/3/

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that `color3` really displays the styles as if they were empty, but `color3.backgroundColor` indicates the desired value.